# Vertical align not working on div

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I'm trying to vertical align a div but it's not working at all for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

```css
body {
border: 1px solid red;
height: 500px;
}
#contactUs {
border: 1px solid blue;
vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id = "contactUs"> Contact Us </div>
```

**Note:**  I do not want absolute positioning answers.

Comment: What? There's no way it can works. `#contactUs` isn't an inline element, but it's not in any container, just in `body`.

Comment: @TheProHands Is body not a container?

Comment: @TheProHands Anyway, that's not true anyway, as I just tried to wrap an outer div around this div, and tried the same css on it, but with same results, so it must be something else.

Comment: *@jessica Nah, what I said is true, dear.*

Comment: @TheProHands I've proved my point by providing a not working example. Why don't you prove that you're right by providing a working example then?

Comment: I know, but I said about the **666**. Okay, but don't need examples, I know about that. I seen your HTML code and edited in developer tools from Chrome.

Comment: Don't just tell me that. Show me. Answer the question below.

Comment: @TheProHands Unless you don't actually know the answer and is just wasting my time, which is seemingly likely.

Comment: Okay, but what do you want to do? Do you want to make the TEXT "Contact Us" be on bottom of the blue border? Is THAT? I'm 14............ more respect. :D

Comment: @TheProHands That's exactly it. But as I've said in the above 'Note', I do not want any absolute positioning answers.

Comment: @jessica possible to use padding-top in either % or fixed and putting the text inside another div? just tried that but not sure if that's what u want. Or do u insist on having the vertical-align?

Comment: @cweitat Page is dynamic, no way to know how much padding is needed, also do not wanted fixed, or absolute positioning answers. The 500px is just an example.

Comment: @cweitat So in short, yes, I'm insisting on the vertical align. Anyway to make it work?

Comment: I finally understand what you want after seeing the new answer.............. please make more explained questions. (comment fixed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vertical alignment effort didn't work because the `vertical-align` property applies only to inline and table-cell elements. ([See the spec for details](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align).)

You can align the `#contactus` div at the bottom of the containing block (`body`) with [**flexbox**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
body {

    display: flex;               /* convert element to flex container */
    flex-direction: column;      /* create a vertical alignment for child elements */
    justify-content: flex-end;   /* align child elements at the end of the container */

    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 500px;
}

#contactUs { border: 1px solid blue; }
```

```html
<div id = "contactUs"> Contact Us </div>
```

*To learn more about flexbox visit:*

- [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)
- [Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) ~ MDN
- [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) ~ CSS-Tricks
- [What the Flexbox?!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLu8EoSxDXHP7xj_y6NIAhy0wuCd4uVdid) ~ YouTube video tutorial

---

*Note that flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE 8 & 9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex). Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix). For a quick way to add all the prefixes you need, post your CSS in the left panel here: [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).*

Comment: Yes! The 'new' finally came out! Because everyone wanted it! Great! Can you comment on all of the new, and exactly what they do?

Comment: I just found a problem. I don't want to align all child elements at the end. Only specific child elements. In this case, only one child element, and that is #contactUs.

Comment: ...Anyway around this?

Comment: Correct. Because there was only one child element in your question. Post another fiddle or question and I'll try to explain.

Comment: There's no way to vertical align just one element to the bottom of its parent? There's only one child element in the example above, because it's just an example, and I try to make all my examples as simple as possible, so answerers don't complain that the code is too long. You can't possibly expect any pages to just have one element, the contact us at the bottom of the page, right? Of course there would have to be other contents.

Comment: Yes, of course there is a way. I'm asking to see a fiddle or a new question because there are various methods for making it happen, and I'm not sure what you're working with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101356/discussion-between-michael-b-and-jessica).

Answer (score -2):

If you only need the "Contact Us" text vertically aligned you can set #contactUs line-height to 500px.

```
line-height:500px;
```

Comment: Where in the post do you see the words 'center aligned'?