# Inline-Flex messes with vertical align

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

Having an `inline` item next to an `inline-flex` with a nested `flex` box messes with the vertical alignment (it ignores the top margin), one solution I found was to put a `::before` in the `inline-flex` item, but I'm not really sure why this fixes it.

The first one ignores the top margin on the label, the top margin works on the second one, because of the `::before`.

```css
label {
  margin: 20px 5px 0 0;
}

.input-container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.with-before::before {
  content: '';
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Top margin ignored:</label>
  <div class="input-container">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>&lt;</button>
      <button>&gt;</button>
    </div>
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <label>Top margin works:</label>
  <div class="input-container with-before">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>&lt;</button>
      <button>&gt;</button>
    </div>
    <input type="text"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding `vertical-alignment: top` and `display: inline-block` to the labels also makes the top margin work, still not sure why. https://codepen.io/GarthDB/pen/veBjvM

Answer (score 4):

The `label` element is inline-level by default. As such, it ignores vertical margins (and padding and height).

> [**8.3 Margin properties: `margin-top`, `margin-right`, `margin-bottom`, `margin-left`, and `margin`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#margin-properties)
>
> [`margin-top` and `margin-bottom`] have no effect on non-replaced
>   inline elements.

However, inline-level elements are subject to the [**`vertical-align`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34938336/3597276) property, and the default value is `baseline`, which means they align vertically per their inline content, such as images, inputs or text.

You can override this behavior with another value, such as `bottom`.

```css
label {
  margin: 20px 5px 0 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.input-container {
  display: inline-flex;
}

button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label>Top margin ignored:</label>
  <div class="input-container">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>&lt;</button>
      <button>&gt;</button>
    </div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<div>
  <label>Top margin works:</label>
  <div class="input-container with-before">
    <div class="buttons">
      <button>&lt;</button>
      <button>&gt;</button>
    </div>
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

As to how the `::before` pseudo-element "fixes" the problem, here are two comments / observations:

1. Adding the `::before` pseudo-element *does not* get the top margin to work. If you remove that margin, you'll see that the label is still aligned to the bottom with the pseudo.
2. I think the pseudo – when empty – shifts the label down because it establishes a new baseline for the container. However, if you add any content to it (I just tried `content: "x"`), the label shifts right back to the top.

I'm pretty sure this is all related to a shifting baseline. Again, just override the `baseline` value in `vertical-align` with `bottom`, `middle` or `top`.

More information:

- [Why is my textarea higher up than its neighbor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32414736/3597276)
- [Vertical align not working on div](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34938100/3597276)