# Div height and position with inner div display inline-block

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how is the inner div position, when it's displayed as inline-block and the outer div has line-height set.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.outer {
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 5px;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

</style>
<body>

<div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner'></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L4przovt/2/
What is surprising here is the positioning of the inner div. I'd expect it to be on top of the outer div but instead it's somewhere in the middle. Could you explain to me what makes it being positioned in this place?

This is possible duplicate of [font-size vs line-height vs actual height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336177/font-size-vs-line-height-vs-actual-height) but my question seems to be more specific. Please tell me if you think that previous answer should be enough for me.

Comment: it's not the middle but it's the baseline. play with `vertical-align` on the inner element and you will understand

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.inner` div is set to `display: inline-block`. That activates the `vertical-align` property, which applies only to [inline-level and table cell elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34938336/3597276).

The default value for `vertical-align` is `baseline`. So that's what you're seeing – the inner div aligns to the [baseline of the content](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34611670/3597276).

To fix the problem, add this to your code:

```
.inner {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed to know.